# Pass variable to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to construct a command which includes a a variable containing IP addresses to a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) but the variable is not passed.

**iplist**

```
8.8.8.8
1.1.1.1
```

**code**

```
with open('iplist', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
    cmd = ['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', '$data']
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(result.stdout)
```

**output**

```
8.8.8.8
1.1.1.1
2020/11/01 10:06:13 could not get records from db /usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb: $data is not a valid IP address
b''
```

Comment: f.read() will read entire file as one string so u need to use readlines() then iterate through those lines.

Comment: You don't want to pass `'$data'` to `subprocess.run`.  If `data` is the string `'1.1.1.1'`, then you just want `data`.  No dollar sign.  No quotes.  You want the contents of the variable `data` to be in the array.

Comment: Your shell obviously has no idea what variables you have used in your Python program, any more than it knows what variable names are used in the C source files for Bash itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
with open('iplist', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as ip_file:
    for ip in ip_file:
      cmd = ['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', ip.strip()]
      result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      print(result.stdout)
```

Comment: @zvi It's a mostly correct answer with an editorial mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use:
`cmd = ['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', data]`

`data` is a variable name.

`$data` is used on other languages (like PHP).

Answer (score 1):

[CYREX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13824946/cyrex) pointed me in right direction. Thank you.

**Final code below**

```
with open('iplist', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    print(data)
    for line in data:
        ip = line.strip() # strip \n lookup will fail
        cmd = ['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', ip]
        print(cmd)
        result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        print(result.stdout)
```

Comment: exactly, my code was missing the strip method, anyway, most important u solved it. regards.