# Append x number variables to a command for subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

This question is based on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64627261/pass-variable-to-subprocess) on creating a command for subprocess.  I am able to send one variable (the ip) as part of the command with the following code:

**iplist**

```
8.8.8.8
1.1.1.1
```

**code for one ip**

```
with open('iplist', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    print(data)
    for line in data:
        ip = line.strip() # strip \n lookup will fail
        cmd = ['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', ip]
        print(cmd)
        result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        print(result.stdout)
```

I would like to send x number of variables (ip) to this command like so:

```
cmd = ['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', '8.8.8.8', '1.1.1.1']
```

**code for x ip's**

```
with open('iplist', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    print(data)
    data1 = [ip.strip() for ip in data] # list comprehension - remove \n from each item in the list
    print(data1)
    data2 = ' '.join(data1)
    print(data2)
    cmd = ['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', data2]
    print(cmd)
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(result.stdout)
```

**output**

```
['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', '8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1']
2020/11/01 13:49:38 could not get records from db /usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb: 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 is not a valid IP address
```

As you can see the ip's need to be seperate variables.

How do I append x number additional ip variables to cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
cmd = ['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', *data1]
```

This will append each IP in `data1` to `cmd` as a unique item at the end of that list.  Here's an illustration:

```
data1 = ['8.8.8.8', '1.1.1.1']
cmd = ['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', *data1]
print(cmd)
```

Result:

```
['./mmdbinspect', '--db', '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', '8.8.8.8', '1.1.1.1']
```

This will work for any number of IPs in `data1`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I didn't realise I could use *data1. I was over thinking, wondering if I had to iterate, join then append cmd.